# Exchange Front End Server 2003 - Can't access accounts

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, outlook, imap

I have a working exchange instance which currently has three servers in it, ExchangeA, ExchangeB, and ExchangeFrontEnd

In this scenario, I expect to be able to configure Exchange Front End to give users access to their mailboxes via IMAP - This does not happen! Any help as to why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the IMAP service on all servers, front-end and back-end; it's disabled by default.